# Inserts with Laravel 5.1 without page reloading

Tags: php, laravel, insert, dropzone.js

I've been using Dropzone for several days and I faced some issues. The idea is: the user selects his file, it uploads and goes in his file directory and some of the file's properties (size, name) go in the DB. I can't do it because when the user uploads the file, the page does not refresh and nothing goes in `Input::file('file')`. I just can't do it. Here is the code i'm using:

```
class UploadController extends Controller {
    public function upload() {
        if(Input::hasFile('file')){
          $file = Input::file('file');
          $user = Auth::id();
          $file->move('uploads/'.$user, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        else {
          echo 'Please select a file first'; 
        }    
     }
```

Here are the two functions in File.php model

```
public function getFileId(){
    $fileName = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $files = File::where('filename', $fileName)->get(); //$fileName
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $fileid = $file->fileid;
        echo $fileid.'<br>';
        Input::file('file')->fileid = $file->fileid; // put fileid as an attribute to the object file for futher usage  
    }       
}
public function incrementFileId(){
    $files = File::orderBy('fileid', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
    foreach($files as $file){
        echo $file->fileid + 1 .' incremented file id<br>';
    }
}
```

So how should my third model function look like to upload the file's properties? DropZone uses Ajax and I though that I should get the file attributes from there but could this be done?!

Comment: What is your exact problem? is the file not being saved properly, do you need to refresh the page when the upload is done, or do you need to send additional information with the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request` instead of `Input`:

```
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
      if ($request->hasFile('file'))
      {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file->move('uploads/'.$user, $file->getClientOriginalName());
      }
```

Comment: Nothing changes using the request

Comment: I just need a model to catch and upload the file properties

Comment: Have you checked your frontend? Is Dropzone properly configured and does it upload the file actually (with an upload button, or  autoProcessQueue: true) ?

On the backend it looks fine, i use the same code.

Comment: Just to ask: what's the difference between my controller using Input:: and yours using Request?

Comment: Well, looking into this there is no difference. See the Input facade is just an alias of the \Illuminate\Http\Request class, with the addition of the get() method, which is just an other way of getting a value with Request::input().

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php#L29-L32
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.php#L15-L18